# How to customize Grid Layout Manager of recycler view?

Tags: android, android-recyclerview

I have successfully implemented a recycler view with the grid layout manner of span count 2.
Now i want to implement something like in the below picture. For this i need to customize my grid layout manager such that the span count for 1 element is 1 and for rest all it is 2. Is there anyway possible.

[image]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use `setSpanSizeLookup` to provide this information to the layout manager.

see docs here:
https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v7/widget/GridLayoutManager.html

Comment: setSpanSizeLookup() only let me know the number of spans occupied by a particular item and its group index. There is no function in  SpanSizeLookup class to set the span count for a particular item.

Comment: https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v7/widget/GridLayoutManager.SpanSizeLookup.html#getSpanSize(int)

You don't call those methods, you provide an implementation of SpanSizeLookup and GridLayoutManager calls it as it needs.